# UFW not allowing udp or tcp traffic on port 514

Tags: rsyslog, ufw

Wondering if someone could tell me why I am not getting any syslog messages passed by UFW, they all go to "UFW AUDIT" and never allow.  What am I missing?

UFW rules:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----                
514/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
514/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
```

UFW.log

```
Jun 15 22:08:04 repper kernel: [2005986.295402] [UFW AUDIT] IN=enp2s0 OUT= MAC=d0:17:c2:0f:e4:d7:90:eb:50:b5:92:85:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.1 DST=10.0.0.51 LEN=186 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=52488 PROTO=UDP SPT=514 DPT=514 LEN=166
```

rsyslog.conf

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
module(load="imudp")
input(type="imudp" port="514")
module(load="imtcp")
input(type="imtcp" port="1514")
$AllowedSender TCP, 10.0.0.51
```